# RDLC report showing red X mark instead of image in IIS 8.0, windows 2012 R2

Tags: asp.net, rdlc, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5, reportviewer2008

I'm sure this has been posted before but none of the solutions provided has actually helped me in this situation. The scenario is this, we have an app which uses report viewer 2008 to render RDLC reports and when checked from inside the server using localhost everything seems to be fine but when we try this app from our end user machine in IE 10 and above, the report logo which is embedded in the RDLC doesn't show up. When using IE 8 (App is originally intended for IE 8) there is a red X mark. So far, we've,

1. Checked the permissions on the folder with the images
2. Re-installed IIS, report viewer
3. Turned off server windows firewall
4. Added app to Trusted sites in IE
5. Enabled enterprise mode

but nothing seems to have an effect. Weird thing is it loads up fine when browsing using localhost from inside the server and any server local to this one, this has me thinking its a permission/firewall issue since the image can't be accessed using the app from outside the local network. Any help would be greatly appreciated since none of the solutions that we saw to this has helped so far, thanks in advance

Comment: Read IIS log files or use Developer Tools of your browser to analyze the requests. Then drill down into the errors related to RDLC.

Comment: hey thanks for your reply, i've tried the IIS logs, couldn't find anything related to the  RDLC, i've tried the dev tools too but nothing related came up, could it be the upstream firewall blocking the image? we recently had a server migration where the host changed their infrastructure, ever since that this is happening